# how to load retrive data from database to dropdown list in yii

Tags: yii

I want to load data to drop down list from database in yii. Can anyone help me to do this? How to use function for this method? Give a simple example for this method. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Yii CActiveFrom::dropDownList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#dropDownList-detail) for doing this. Here is a sample:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($yourModelObject, 'attirbute', CHtml::listData(YourModel::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name')); ?>
```

Note, `id`  will placed as value and `name` will placed as text of each generated `option` tag.

Comment: can u help me to use controller for this method

Comment: DropDown is a **view** widget and you need to use it in the view. But you can put `CHtml::listData(YourModel::model()->findAll()` in your controller and pass the result to your view.

Comment: it gives an error model is undefined